# PHP Pagination does not change

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

Anything over 2 pages this does not work. If you choose the 3rd page. You stay on the 3rd page. And all the links for other pages are the 3rd page.

```
 <?php
            wp_reset_postdata();

            $pagenum      = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;


            if ( $product_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) {
                echo '<div class="pagination-wrap">';
                $page_links = paginate_links( array(
                    'current'   => $pagenum,
                    'total'     => $product_query->max_num_pages,
                    'base'      => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
                    'format'    => '',
                    'type'      => 'array',
                    'prev_text' => __( '&laquo; Previous', 'dokan' ),
                    'next_text' => __( 'Next &raquo;', 'dokan' )


                                        ) );

                echo '<ul class="pagination"><li>';
                echo join("</li>\n\t<li>", $page_links);
                echo "</li>\n</ul>\n";
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: perhaps you should indicate that this is wordpress, otherwise "paginate_links()" will mean nothing...

Comment: I have added this. Need help :)